# Why is socket slowing down after a number of reads?

Tags: sockets, tcpclient, tcp

I've written a simple test client (VB.Net) that uses the TcpClient class to send a small "command" byte array (6 or 7 bytes) to a hardware device, across the company network. The device responds with a byte array (approx 48kb) which my client app reads. I know the exact length of the returned array, so I repeatedly read the socket in a loop until I have it all:-

```
Dim read_data() As Byte

Dim stream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

' Send the "command"
stream.Write(data, 0, commandByteArray)

' Read the response
Using ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()

    Dim temp_read(16384) As Byte
    Try
        Do
            Dim bytes_read = stream.Read(temp_read, 0, temp_read.Length)
            ms.Write(temp_read, 0, bytes_read)
        Loop While ms.Length < expectedResponseSize
    Catch ex As IOException
        ' No more data
    End Try

    read_data = ms.ToArray()

    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Using
```

This code is wired up to a button click event. Each time I run it, the stopwatch shows it takes an average of **5ms** to read the 48kb byte array back. However if I repeatedly click the button several times per second, after a few seconds the time reported by the stopwatch starts to increase, and eventually settles at around **50ms**. If I disconnect, reconnect and try again then the time returns to 5ms (until I start rapidly clicking the button again).

Any idea what's causing this? I'm assuming it's something in the network protocol or network hardware, e.g. something adapting the connection to the increased data throughput?

**Edit:** as mentioned in the comment below, I've tried disabling Nagling (`socket.NoDelay = true`) but it had no effect, although my understanding is that this would be more likely to improve throughput of very small messages, not large ones like this.

Comment: At what frequency are you sending the commands? Is Nagling enabled? This is about the only issue I can think of here.

Comment: @usr The commands are currently triggered by a button click, so generally no more than a handful a second, but the problem manifests even when sending (say) one per second. Re Nagling, if you mean setting the socket's `NoDelay` to True - it does speed things up a little initially (3-4ms instead of 5ms) but the slowdown still occurs, again down to around 50ms.